# Text in the middle of button - can't center it

Tags: html, css, text-align

http://jsfiddle.net/8zkqu/1/

```
            <div id="button" class="g">
                <p>Discover me!</p>
            </div> <!-- id button class g -->
```

and .css file looks like that

```
#button{

    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-weight:  bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.g {
    background-color: rgb(94,179,74);
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid green;
    position: absolute;


}
```

Its start to being annoying! How to center text inside buttoN?

Comment: Use a Javascript console to inspect that element and you'll see the `p` has a padding that's throwing it off... *Vertically*, which is what I assume you are after. Why in the world are you constructing a *button" out of a `div` with a nested `p` you want right-positioned?

Comment: I didnt I can inspect anything with java. I'm newbie. Thx for info gonna check it out

Comment: but still padding: 0px; to P doesnt work.

Comment: Sorry, it's margin. Why don't you use a `button` with a `span` inside it like `<button type="button"><span>Drizzle</span</button>`?

Comment: if you want to use the <p> just edit the margin for the <p> as its creating your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're looking to [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) the element ?

Try with `display:table-cell`

**HTML**

```
<div id="button" class="g">
    <span>Discover me!</span>
</div> <!-- id button class g -->
```

**CSS**

```
#button{
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 40px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-weight:  bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.g {
    background-color: rgb(94,179,74);
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zkqu/2/).

`Text-aling:center` centers the element *horinzontal* and `vertical-align:middle` *vertical*.

Answer (score 0):

This update to the CSS should do the trick:

```
.g p {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/BLQWb/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
#button p{    
margin: 0px;
line-height: 40px;
}
```

Margins are added to `<p>` elements by default, the code above removes them. And line-height centers the text in the button, to achieve this in the future set the line-height to be equal to the button height.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Add this to your CSS:

```
#button p{
     line-height:0px;
}
```